# Using Rollup to process Sass as well as CSS Modules

Tags: sass, build, rollupjs, rollup-plugin-postcss

we are using rollup to make the build. We've currently only had Sass, but are trying to also use css modules for some custom components. The configuration in the rollup.config.js is

```
postcss({
   extract: false,
   modules: true
}),
scss({
   outputStyle: 'compressed'
}),
```

However on running the build we get an error saying 'default' is not exported by the css module file. The Css module file is foo.module.css and only defines the css classes. As its meant to be a css module, the classes should be put onto a default export, so not quite sure why rollup is complaining here.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked by removing the scss configuration key and adding a key for use with value 'sass' into the postcss config key.

```
postcss({
   extract: false,
   modules: true,
   use: ['sass']
}),
```